# Index Construction and Factor Analysis after or before Multiple Imputation?

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, data-imputation, multiple-imputation, mice

**Background:** So I have a dataset with 32 Variables. There are several missing values so I decided to impute them with the `mice` package in R. However, I plan to combine most of those variables through factor analysis, so that I am only left with 12 variables in my final analysis (with which I will conduct a multilevel analysis).

**Question:** should I combine the variables before imputation and then impute with my smaller 12 Variables or with the "raw" dataset of 32 variables?

I know you can do passive imputation, where you can include combined items, but I can hardly just use the factor scores from the unimputed dataset to be used in the passive imputation process like this (`meth["Index1"] <- "~I(x1*0.789+x2*0.678+x3*0.786)"`, or can I?

Because here is another problem I have: I also read that you should include interaction terms, but my interaction terms will be between those indices. So I would need to have my indices already created in order to passively impute the interaction terms, or am I overthinking this?

I have read some similar questions here, but nothing that would really answer my specific question [(1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202058/multiple-imputation-and-factor-analyses) [(2)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203543/multiple-imputation-before-or-after-creating-variables) [(3)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/factor-analysis-on-multiply-imputed-data/66843#66843).

If I can help you out with further information, please let me know!